# How to handle web form errors on a page where, onload, the said form is way below the visible section of the page?

Tags: user-interface, frontend, backend, client-side, user-experience

How may I handle web form errors on a page where, onload, the said form is way below the visible section of the page? As it is now, users have to scroll down to see the result of their submission. Some users may not care to do that which is a user experience (UX) concern to me. How may I solve this problem?

Comment: Automatically scroll the page to have the form in view?